# How to get Views Bulk Operations to work when showing a view programmatically?

Tags: 7, views

I have shown a view programmatically using the code:

```
  $view = views_get_view('my_view');
  $view->set_display('panel_pane_2');
  $view->set_arguments( array('node', '241+254') );
  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();
  print $view->render();
```

The view shows up and the VBO form shows up too. However, the VBO actions do nothing. They simply redirect to the home page. The action functions don't even get called.

Is there something extra needed in the code above or is this a bug in VBO?

Extra info (just in case): the code above is entered in a Panels pane through Page Manager.